# Spark Driver variable accessible from Executor viz foreachPartition

Tags: apache-spark

I am try to use spark to process some IDs, and want to dedup for each batch

if my code is like

```
HashSet<String> uniqueID = new HashSet<>();
foreachPartition((VoidFunction<Iterator<T>>) idIterator -> {

...
//add unique id
if (!uniqueID.contains(id)){
uniqueID.add(id)
}
});
```

in this case, since foreachpartition execute on worker node, but I define my hashset outside of foreachpartition, will it still work? I knew reduce by key will be best to handle this and I am changing it, but just to analyze a existing code behavior

Comment: Do you want data returned?

Comment: Not exactly, I will call an external database.

Comment: ok. Did you try? foreachPartition is parameterless and there are issues with Serialization to consider.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on coding.

Answer (score 0):

Move hashset inside foreachPartition and based on your comments such an approach is possible. However, you will need to partition such that Id value is in same partition and not over partitions. On Serialization error, it does occur - just ran a check to be sure. Moreover, your approach does not fit the Spark way of parallel processing.

Comment: Thanks, but for current production code, if I put like above way, whether it is still perform the hash dedup as expected? or it dose not work at all?

Comment: Checked - I got serialization error just now based on your approach.